# Delayed publish - version of page

Tags: publishing, publishing-service

EDIT: I was using dialog in Sitecore Rocks - seems there is a better one in actual admin interface where I can set publish to/from dates for each version..
Just testing to see if this works..

So, I am looking into delayed publishing, and want to know what I can acheive out of the box, and what I might need to use a plugin for.

Simple example:

I have a page, that is already published, i.e. the homepage.

I want to make a change to this page (in this case, on a field on page itself, and not any dynamically bound content), at a specific Date/Time but don't want to have to publish at that specific moment.. so, I set the "Publishable from" date to my required date/time, and publish item. Issue I am having is this causes the page to become unpublished (and therefore I get an error) until the required time comes along. I want to keep V1 active until V2's publish time as come and that becomes the active version..

I've already enabled `<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.PublishAgent" ...` in the config file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the publish date for the latest version. You need to make use of the `Versions tab` to be able to set which version to be published and when. Please see screenshot below

[image]

**Example**

Let say you have 2 versions on the item. Version 2 contains the updated data. So, you need to set this version to be published at your defined date/time.

Comment: Thank you. this is what I needed.. I was doing via Sitecore rocks, which doesn't correctly set the publish date it seems.